# Row Number Not Align Properly

Tags: devexpress

I am DevExpress GridView when I search something in search panel. Row number not Align in Proper Way.
Can Anyone Please Help this?
Thank you[Screen Shots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKLIb.png)

Comment: Can you provide a screen shot that demonstrates this issue?

Comment: I am added screen shots

Comment: I fail to see what the issue is. Are you trying to have the numbers aligned to the left or right of the cell instead of the current center alignment?